# Why is StreamReader.ReadLine() ignoring my newline characters?

Tags: c#

I'm reading the contents of a text file. The text file clearly is in paragraph form with a space in between each paragraph. When I load and display it, it's all together as one large paragraph, which was not expected.

```
currentLine = sr.ReadLine();

while (currentLine != "[/CONTENT]")
{
    m_content += currentLine;

    currentLine = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

I open the file as such:

```
// Open the file.
sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
```

Why is it ignoring the text file's newline characters?

Edit: I can explicitly add a newline (\n, etc.) in the text file, but it does nothing when it's read. It just reads like "This is some\n text." without breaking the line when read by the program.

Edit #2: I'm reading in a script, as you can notice the /CONTENT tag, so I'm unable to simply just read to the end of the file.

Comment: ReadLine reads until it encounters the first `\n` or similar EndStream marker. That is the very definition of a "line" - everything up to the first `\n`, not including said `\n`. The actuall marker can actually vary on the OS a bit as we never quite standartised how strings are event represented in memory (char[] or specific class). The .NET Code will actually get the local value via String.Newline or some similar runtime constant.

Comment: To parse anything - be it a script, a CSV file or even a XML file, you can not actually use stuff like ReadLines. Most of those have provisions for "multi line" content. You have to continue to read until you got a full segment (like everything till the next closing bracket) to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you Call the `ReadLine()` function it basically takes off all the formatting and returns just the clean string.

And about your `\n` problem try this :

```
currentLine = sr.ReadLine();

while (currentLine != "[/CONTENT]")
{
    m_content += Environment.NewLine+currentLine;
    currentLine = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: But this will add newline with every line even if it does not present in the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadAllLines` and join the resulting lines with new line

For example

```
string path = "path/to/file";
string contents = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(path));
```